# Error Displays Successfully But Record is Still Inserted in the Database

Tags: apex, error-messages

I have two apex classes and one trigger. `ApexClass1` handles the record insertion, while `ApexClass2` handles mostly all the computations and errors. `ApexClass2` is called on the trigger `Trigger1`. All of these happen in just a single object.

Here's the problem:

Everytime an error is successfully displayed, the record is still inserted to the database. It isn't supposed to be committed to the database since there's an error.

Note that I am getting the desired error message, so I don't really know what's happening.

Meanwhile, here are some code from the apex classes:

**ApexClass1**

```
/*
some code
*/

if(!objectList.isEmpty()) {
    try {
         insert objectList;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
         return null;
    } 
}
```

**ApexClass2**

```
/*
some code
*/

if(object__c.Field__c < 0) {
    object__c.Field__c.addError('Field cannot have negative value.');
}
```

Comment: If you are catching the error then the record will be inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By catching and handling the `DmlException` generated by `addError`, you are stopping the default behaviour of a transaction rollback. You can add your own rollback:

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
try {
     insert objectList;
}
catch(Exception e) {
     Database.rollback(sp);
     return null;
}
```

But its best to start out not catching exceptions so your code follows the normal platform patterns and only add catches if you are certain they help.

Comment: I've also tried your suggestion, but no luck. But thanks for your help.

Comment: hey, your suggestion is working now. I've just added an `else` statement and put `return null` inside it, again, thank you. :)